# How child elements associated with input search text can also be listed, using TreeListFilter?

Tags: javascript, html

Using TreeListFilter.js from http://wiki.aiwsolutions.net/2014/03/12/tree-list-filter-plugin/

I tried to modify the code to make child elements (ul/li) of a matched input search text be listed as well, but it is not working. Still, display stops at the matching level in the unordered list.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: Can you show us the code you wrote?

Answer (score 0):

I think the key change you need to make is to search the current node's immediate text *only* first, then ensure this result is communicated to child nodes.

```
// Search own text only (not including children)
var text = liObject.clone().children().remove().end().text();

// Match or parent is visible
display = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(filterValue) >= 0 || parentDisplay;

if (liObject.children().length > 0) {
    for (var j = 0; j < liObject.children().length; j++) {
        // Ask child to search self and let them know parents display result
        var subDisplay = filterList(jQuery(liObject.children()[j]), filterValue, display);

        // If child is visible at this stage, make parent visible, if 
        // parent visible, this will already be true
        display = display || subDisplay;
    }
}
```

Full example is here: https://jsfiddle.net/on2u2584/1/